# The location of the compressed layer on the file system for the Docker image

Tags: docker

Where are the compressed docker image layers located? Where can I find them on my local file system?
It should be located inside /var/lib/docker, but I'm not sure where the compressed versions of them are stored.
In the image's manifest, for instance, each layer has its compressed  sha256.
According to the image manifest.json, I would like to find the actual compressed layer files.

Comment: Please check this article https://medium.com/@BeNitinAgarwal/docker-containers-filesystem-demystified-b6ed8112a04a

Comment: Usually the content in `/var/lib/docker` is installation- and configuration-specific, and you shouldn't be manually doing anything in that directory.  The actual layer format will depend on the Docker storage backend (and likely is not compressed).  What's your goal with this setup?

Comment: Thank you for your response, @DavidMaze. To export a Docker image, I can run the `*docker save [IMAGEID]*` command. There is a problem with it, as it is not compressed, and the checksum of each layer is different from the checksum in manifest.json.
By comparing the sha256 in manifest.json, I can verify that each layer's checksum is the current one.